# why did the elasticsearch MSI installer disappear?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-aggregation

Why did the elasticsearch MSI installer disappear?
They only offer the zip file now.

Is there any reason why they remove it?

Comment: From the [official site](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack/7.17/elasticsearch-breaking-changes.html#breaking_717_packaging_changes), they discontinued it saying that _These packages were previously released in beta and didn’t receive widespread adoption._ I think that the majority of the elasticsearch installations are linux/container/k8s based, specially the paid ones, which is what will make elastic prioritize things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@leandrojmp is correct. Looking at the download stats, MSI was a tiny fraction of them with a very different approach that never fully matured or saw much uptake. You should be able to do everything with the ZIP file as well; unless you're heading to the containerized world anyway.